# Choose distinct elements that satisfy certain conditions in $\Bbb{Z}_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to understand the proof of a proposition in a paper as below:

[image]

I cannot understand how and why the condition $km<n$ lead to choosing $a_1,\dots,a_m\in \Bbb{Z}_n$ such that the listed elements are all distinct. I guess that Axiom of Choice applies here, but the method of choosing those elements are not stated in the proof.

Next, I am thinking whether such result can be generalized. For example, if $p+q+r<n$ where $p,q,r$ are positive integers, can we choose $a_1,a_2,a_3\in \Bbb{Z}_n$ such that
\begin{align*}
&a_1,a_1+1,a_1+2,\dots,a_1+(p-1);\\
&a_2,a_2+p,a_2+2p,\dots,a_2+(q-1)p;\\
&a_3,a_3+pq,a_3+2pq,\dots,a_3+(r-1)pq
\end{align*}
are all distinct in $\Bbb{Z}_n$.

Remark:
$A_1,\dots,A_m$ is a complete decomposition of $\Bbb{Z}_n$ if $A_1+\dots+A_m=\Bbb{Z}_n$ and $A_1,\dots,A_m$ are pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by $\mathbb Z_n$ you meant $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, the integers mod $n$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

This proof seems dubious to me. Take $k=3, n=54$, then $m=4$ and $n=(k-1)k^{m-1}$. As such $a_m\equiv a_m+(k-1)k^{m-1}\pmod n$ and you would never be able to find such distinct numbers.

However, I can say one thing: this has absolutely nothing to do with the Axiom of Choice. It is used when you are choosing infinitely many things from infinite sets. Here you are choosing finitely many integers. Even if you were to choose infinitely many representatives from $\mathbb Z$, it can be easily well-ordered (e.g. by absolute value) and requires no choice whatsoever.

Comment: May I know how you come up with the counterexample?

Comment: @AlanWang The key observation is that when $n|(k-1)k^{m-1}$ this does not work. For simplicity say they are equal. The minimality of $m$ forces $(k-1)k^{m-1}=n>k^{m-1}$, i.e. $k>2$, so $k$ is at least 3. As long as we have $m$ we will have everything, and the remaining is basically trial. I don't recall why I chose 4, but it should not be difficult to construct a counterexample from here. As for why I thought a counterexample exists, I tried to justify why the elements in a row are different $\pmod n$ to understand the proof, and then I came across the last one.